# Why does only one of the two following functions print the correct conversion: text-file to 16 and 8-bit displays?

Tags: c, arrays, prototype, endianness

Why does only one of the two following functions in my programs main function print the correct conversion of a text-file(that has only the single character 'e' in it) to Sixteen and Eight Bit displays of that character 'e'? For example it only prints:   'e' = 101

101 = 01100101000000000 0000000000000000

0 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

and it should read:
'e' = 101

101 = 01100101000000000 0000000000000000

101 = 01100101 00000000 00000000 00000000

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void displaySixteenBits(char *value );//prototype
void displayEightBits( char *value );//prototype


int main(void)
{
   FILE *ptr_file;
   char buf[1000];

   ptr_file = fopen("input.txt","r");

   if (!ptr_file)
      return 1;

   while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
      printf("The file read: \t");
   printf("%s\n",buf);
   /*Only one of the following two lines of code prints*/
   displaySixteenBits( buf );
   displayEightBits( buf );

   fclose(ptr_file);
   return 0;

}//end main



/* Function to display text file character to 16 bits*/
void displaySixteenBits( char *value )
{
   char c;

   int displayMask = 1 << 31;

   printf( "%10u = ", *value );

   for ( c = 1; c <= 32; ++c ) {

      putchar( *value & displayMask ? '1' : '0' );
      *value <<= 1;

      if (c % 16 == 0 ){
         putchar( ' ' );
      }
   }

   putchar( '\n' );
}//end display sixteen bits

/* Function to display text file character to eight bits*/
void displayEightBits( char *value )
{
   char c;

   int displayMask =  1 << 31;

   printf( "%10u = ", *value );

   for ( c = 1; c <= 32; ++c ) {

      putchar( *value & displayMask ? '1' : '0' );
      *value <<= 1;

      if (c % 8 == 0 ){
         putchar( ' ' );
      }

   }

   putchar( '\n' );
}//end display eight bits
```

Comment: It's not clear from your post the exact contents of the input file and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int displayMask = 1 << 31;` might work coincidentally, at best. At the worst of times, it won't do what you want it to do at all. Perhaps you meant `unsigned long displayMask = 1UL << 31;`.

Given our understanding of `*value` being a `char`, and `displayMask` having a binary value of `0b10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`, the following looks quite suspicious:

`*value & displayMask` How often is it that any `char` will have a value large enough to require 32 bits? Perhaps you meant `unsigned char displayMask = ~(UCHAR_MAX >> 1);`, after all. While we're on that note, it might be wise to cast `*value` to an `unsigned char` there.

`8` seems like a magic number. Perhaps you meant `CHAR_BIT`? You can include `UCHAR_MAX` and `CHAR_BIT` from the `<limits.h>` header.

`printf( "%10u = ", *value );` is a little less cromulent, but just to be on the safe side it might be a good idea to cast `*value` to an `unsigned int` there.